# How Logical XOR

Tags: c#, .net

I understand that for boolean values Exclusive OR says the output will be on if the inputs are different. [link](http://www.learn-c.com/boolean.htm)

But how does it work on non boolean values like below. In C# or Javascript, how is its value "10" for below code. Can anyone explain this for me please?

```
  Console.WriteLine(9^3);
```

Comment: it works like bitwise operation (like `|`, `&`)

Comment: Convert to binary and apply XOR to individual bits.

Comment: 1100(12) ^ 1010(10) = 0110(6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the impression you are thinking in purely logical terms, where the result must be true or false, 1 or 0. The `^` operator *does* act this way, but as a *bitwise* operator is does it *per bit*, one at a time, instead of on the whole value at once. It's not that 9 and 3 are both "true", and so the result must be false. It's that `9` is `1001` and `3` is `0011`, and when you check each of the corresponding bits with xor you get `1010`, which is `10`:

```
  1001  (9)
^ 0011  (3)
------
  1010  (10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operators perform operation on the bits stored in the memory.

Hence take equalent binary value for each decimal number and perform the operation.

```
 9 ---Binary Value ---> 0000 1001
 3 ---Binary Value ---> 0000 0011
      Perform EXOR (^) ------------
                        0000 1010  ---- Decimal Value --> 10
```